# Can we get id from repeat block to get element in Javascript?

Tags: visualforce, javascript

```
<apex:page controller="weatherAddRowController1" id="thePage" sidebar="false">
<script>
function calculate1(sev, num){

    var res;
    sev = document.getElementById("{!$Component.myForm:pb:therepeat:pg:pg3:sev}").value;
    num = document.getElementById("{!$Component.myForm.pb.therepeat.pg.pg4.num}").value;
    alert('hisdbdj dsfhnk '+sev);
    if(sev=='Simple'){
        res=num*4;
        <!--document.getElementById("{!$Component.myForm.pb.therepeat.pg.pg5.res}");-->
        alert(res);
    }
    else if(sev=='Medium'){
        res=num*6;  
        alert(res);
    }
    else if(sev=='Complex'){
        res=num*12;
        alert(res);
    }
}  

</script>
<apex:form id="myForm">

<apex:pageblock id="pb" >
    <apex:pageBlockButtons >
        <apex:commandbutton value="Add" action="{!Add}" rerender="pb"/>
        <apex:commandbutton value="Save" action="{!Save}"/>
        <apex:commandButton value="Calculate" onclick="javascript:calculate1()"/> 
        <apex:commandButton value="Reset" action="{!reset}"/>           
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    <apex:repeat value="{!lstInner}" var="e1" id="therepeat">
                <apex:panelGrid id="pg" columns="5">

                <apex:panelGrid id="pg1" headerClass="Name">
                    <apex:facet name="header">Delete</apex:facet>
                    <apex:commandButton value="Del" action="{!Del}" rerender="pb1">
                        <apex:param name="rowToBeDeleted" value="{!e1.recCount}" assignTo="{!selectedRowIndex}"></apex:param>
                    </apex:commandButton>
                </apex:panelGrid>   

                <apex:panelGrid id="pg2" title="SPD" >
                    <apex:facet name="header">Components</apex:facet>
                       <apex:inputField value="{!e1.est.Components__c}"/>
                    <apex:param name="test" value="{!e1.est.Components__c}"  />          
                </apex:panelGrid>

                <apex:panelGrid id="pg3" >
                    <apex:facet name="header">Severity</apex:facet>
                    <!--<input id="sev" value="{!e1.est.Severity__c}"/>-->
                    <apex:inputField id="sev" value="{!e1.est.Severity__c}"/>
                </apex:panelGrid>

                <apex:panelGrid id="pg4" >
                    <apex:facet name="header">Number of components</apex:facet>
                    <apex:inputField id="num" value="{!e1.est.Number_of_Components__c}"/>
                </apex:panelGrid>

                <apex:panelGrid border="0" id="pg5" >
                    <apex:facet name="header">Result</apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputText id="res"> </apex:outputText>
                </apex:panelGrid>

            </apex:panelgrid>
        </apex:repeat>
     </apex:pageblock>
   </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Whats ur exact target there

Comment: Please provide more detail on what you are trying to do. I would use jQuery to get elements, but I need to know what your goal is to provide you pointers.

Answer (score 0):

I am not totaly sure (because I need to see html page to tell you more) but I think that jQuery advanced selectors:

```
Child Selector (“parent > child”) 
Selects all direct child elements specified by "child" of elements specified by "parent".
```

Where repeat is parent. It should do the job you need.

But If you have to use JavaScript try :

```
var array = document.getElementsById('therepeat');
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are looking for but waht i understood is that you need to select element by using document.getElementById("someId") even when your code is generating inside a repeat tag.
Due to repeat tag the Id of elements are assigned dynamically and you will get id as "js0:js1:.." and you have no way to know what the id is.

My answers is to select using jQuery element property selector as:

1. Give every element and Id like "idxMyElement" so your elements will be like id="js0:js1.idxMyElement" .. id="js0:js2.idxMyElement" .
2. Now use $("input[id*='idxMyElement']"); this will give you an array of all the elemets with this "idxMyElement" id.

Hope this helps you.